# How can I combine and synchronize multiple social networks?

Tags: webapp-rec

I've accounts on Facebook, XING, and LinkedIn and several mail accounts all over the place. I would like to keep control of all those people, without uploading my whole address book to the sites.

Is there desktop software that can help manage multiple networks without disclosing too much information to the networks?

Answer (score 0):

I use a service called MemoToo and you can [check out how I set it up on my blog](http://blog.hinshelwood.com/archive/2010/07/07/the-search-for-a-single-point-of-truth.aspx).

If you go to http://memotoo.com and setup an account you can have your contacts synced with tons of services including:

- Outlook
- Google Contacts
- Google Calander
- Facebook (One way)
- LinkedIn (One way)
- Windows Live Contacts
- Yahoo Contacts
- Twitter
- Windows Mobile
- Android
- Plaxo
- Soocial
- SheduleWorld
- UNYK
- Vodafone 360 (this is a realy crap service though)
- And tones more

Its also very cheap and you only need to pay £12 per year if you have more than 50 contacts. I have 2000+ and it work just fine.

I did have a couple of hours of De-duping to do afterwords with so many services, but once you have sone that once all is good. Most dups can be deleted, but if you have a contact on Facebook and LinkedIn it is better to merge them.

The problem I have with most sync tool or scripts is that they are one time afairs that leave tonds of duplicates when you re-run them. MemoToo knows which contacts are on multiple services and automaticaly merges them once you tell it that they are the same person.